# Scala: when to use explicit type annotations

Tags: scala, types

I've been reading a lot of other people's Scala code recently, and one of the things that I have  difficultly with (coming from Java) is a lack of explicit type annotations.

It's certainly convenient when writing code to be able to leave out type annotations -- however when reading code I often find that explicit type annotations help me to understand at a glance what code is doing more easily.

The Scala style guide (http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html) doesn't seem to provide any definitive guidance on this, stating:

> Use type inference where possible, but put clarity first, and favour explicitness in public APIs.

To my mind, this is a bit contradictory. While it's clearly obvious what type this variable is:

```
val tokens = new HashMap[String, Int]
```

It's not so obvious what type this one is:

```
val tokens = readTokens()
```

So, if I was putting clarity first I would probably annotate all variables where the type is not already declared on the same line.

Do any Scala practitioners have guidance on this? Am I crazy to be considering adding type annotations to my local variables? I'm particularly interested in hearing from folks who spend a lot of time reading scala code (for example, in code reviews), as well as writing it.

Comment: The Scala community is remains divided on a lot of stylistic issues, from what I've seen.  Find a style you like, that is clear to you and your team, and stick with it!

Comment: What I find really important in that part of the style guide is the bit about public fields/methods. Relying on type inference there can break encapsulation, and that's a serious issue. For anything local or private, if I really have a doubt, I just rely on my IDE to infer the type for me, so it doesn't matter to me - I would only use explicit type annotations on private methods or fields if it serves to document something unexpected.

Answer (score 4):

> It's not so obvious what type this one is:
>
> ```
> val tokens = readTokens()
> ```

Good names are important: the name is plural, ergo it returns some collection of some kind. The most general collection types in Scala are `Traversable` and `Iterator`, and they mostly share a common interface, so it's not really important which one of the two it is. The name also talks about "reading tokens", ergo it obviously should return `Token`s in some fashion. And last but not least, the method call has parentheses, which according to the style guide means it has side-effects, so I wouldn't count on being able to traverse the collection more than once.

Ergo, the return type is something like

```
Traversable[Token]
```

or

```
Iterator[Token]
```

and which of the two it is doesn't really matter because their client interfaces are mostly identical.

Note also that the latter constraint (only traversing the collection once) isn't even captured in the type, even if you *were* providing an explicit type, you would *still* have to look at the name and the style!

Comment: This is a great point. Prior to diving into Scala, Python and Javascript were my main languages. Because types annotations aren't built into those languages, I found it useful to rely on good choice of names to keep my programs readable. For the example of `readTokens` returning a `Map[String, Int]`, I would probably call it `countsByToken`.